# Page methods in asp.net not working

Tags: asp.net-2.0

I have a page method like following,

```
protected void authUser(string uid,string pass)
{}
```

And I am making call from javascript like this

```
PageMethods(uid,pass,success,error)
```

But it's not working

Comment: Your method in c# needs to be public and static

Answer (score 0):

There are a few steps to ensure your page methods will work.

1. Ensure you have a script manager defined with page methods enabled

> <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="True" />

2. Define your code behind with the web method attribute

   > ```
   > [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]        
   > public static bool authUser(string uid,string pass)
   > {
   >     return true; // Do validation returning true if authenticated
   > }
   > ```
3. Define methods in client script to call the web method.

   > PageMethods.authUser(uid, pass, function(result) { /* succeed */ }, function(error) { });